# T-SQL Only find duplicate records based on one column x

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
clm_id  process_id     note
N500    11            leg fracture
N500    12            leg fracture
N500    13            delivery
N500    14            headache
N501    5             surgery
N501    6             fever
N501    7             prostate
N501    8             prostate
```

This is the desired result:

```
claim_id process_id    note
N500     11           leg fracture
N500     12           leg fracture
N501     7            prostate
N501     8            prostate
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate? Same claim_id and note? Also--please add an attempt at the code. We are not a code-writing service, but are happy to help with issues in your own attempts :)

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick option is with `sum() over ()`

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Cnt = sum(1) over (Partition By  clm_id,note)
     From  YourTable
)
Select clm_id
      ,process_id
      ,note
 From  cte 
 Where Cnt>1
```

**Returns**

```
clm_id  process_id  note
N500    11          leg fracture
N500    12          leg fracture
N501    7           prostate
N501    8           prostate
```

Comment: Thanks,you made my day

Comment: @anonymous Happy to help